# Store defaultdict into a text file

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict `test` which looks like that :

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [['Age','19'], ['Name','Peter'], ['Country','Australia]], 'B': [['Age','22'], ['Name','Paul'], ['Country','England']], 'C': ... ]]})
```

I want to output that defauldict into new files with keys as filenames. I can do it with :

```
for k,v in test.items():
        with open("{}_test.txt".format(k), "w") as f:
                csv='\n'.join(['\n'.join(t) for t in v])
                f.write("%s,%s\n" % (k, csv))
```

That works, but the problem I have is : when I check the content of the file, it looks like that :

```
cat A_test.txt

    A,Age
    19
    Name
    Peter
    Country
    Australia
    
cat B_test.txt

    B,Age
    22
    Name
    Paul
    Country
    England
```

I don't want the "`A,`" and "`B,`" at the beginning of the first line of the files. It should be like that :

```
cat A_test.txt
    
        Age
        19
        Name
        Peter
        Country
        Australia
        
    cat B_test.txt
    
        Age
        22
        Name
        Paul
        Country
        England
```

Any solution to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line, remove the k, which prints the key ?

```
f.write("%s\n" % ( csv))
```

Comment: Yes, that was logic.. Thanks :)